# Coverage.py Vs pytest-cov

Tags: python, coverage.py, pytest-cov

The [documentation](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en) of `coverage.py` says that `Many people choose to use the pytest-cov plugin, but for most purposes, it is unnecessary.` So I would like to know what is the difference between these two? And which one is the most efficient ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 24, accepted):

pytest-cov uses coverage.py, so there's no different in efficiency, or basic behavior.  pytest-cov auto-configures multiprocessing settings, and ferries data around if you use pytest-xdist.

Comment: One unusual case where you'd rather use coverage directly is when you test the coverage of a pytest plugin, as discussed in [how-to-get-coverage-reporting-when-testing-a-pytest-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62221654/how-to-get-coverage-reporting-when-testing-a-pytest-plugin)

Comment: So If I want to create a github action and calculate my code coverage using `coverage run -m pytest` do I need to install `coverage.py` also or just existing `pytest-cov` will do the work for me?

Comment: When you install pytest-cov, it pulls in coverage.py as a dependency.  If you want to use `coverage run -m pytest`, you don't need pytest-cov at all.